# Angular ui-grid with cellNav - how to remove blue border when focused?

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I am using ui-grid with CellNav feature on: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/309_editable_with_cellnav

Can't figure out which CSS style adds blue shadowed border around the grid when focused.
Which CSS class should I override in order to get rid of this border?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This will stop the blue border appearing.

```
.ui-grid-cell-focus { 
    border: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: this removes the shadow around the individual cells - the question references the shadow around the whole grid - the answer below referencing .ui-grid-focuser:focus {
  box-shadow: none !important;
} answers the question.

Answer (score 7):

Finally I got it after read the source code, use this one:

```css
.ui-grid-focuser:focus {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```